# Calculating html element (div) width with javascript/dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Normally when you have a div created in html. You can check its width with offsetWidth or style.width (if declared).  However if the innerHTML is changed such that the width of the div is also change, neither of those functions work (not sure, but they haven't in my cases).

some code:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHtml = "asdfasdfasdfasdfsdfasdfasdfad";
alert(div.style.width); // this is nothing
alert(div.offsetWidth); // this is 0
```

How do you get the width of the div above?

Comment: perhaps you'd find [dojox/html/metrics](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/html/metrics) useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get width value of element that wasn't appended to document.

so you should append it to page, than you can get width,

here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/etMWn/2)

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but for the many people landing here from google I'll provide it.

This is the way to do it in dojo 1.7+. With the geometry module you can get and set the width of the content (not including padding or border). This ignores box-sizing.

```
require(['dojo/dom-geometry'], function(domGeom) {
    var myDivNode = dojo.query('div')[0];
    var contentBox = domGeom.getContentBox(myDivNode);
    alert(contentBox.w);

    // This is how to set width/height
    domGeom.setContentSize(myDivNode, {w: 100, h: 100});
});
```

Source: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/contentBox.html